# Is there an easy way of using SQL Update in an Insert statement

Tags: sql-server

I’m fairly new to sql queries so bear with me.
I got this Insert statement:

```
insert into Biztalk.Attestregler

SELECT 'A' AS STATUS
    , Anv
    , convert(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, @antalkorningar, (convert(DATETIME, Startdat))), 112) AS Startdate
    , Slutdate
    , Kstfrom
    , KSTtom
    , Projfrom
    , Projtom
    , Kontofrom
    , Kontotom
    , Amount
    , Ersattare
    , Eskalera
    , 0
FROM Agresso.Attestregler
WHERE rtrim(ltrim(Anv + '' + Startdate + '' + Slutdate + '' + Kstfrom + '' + KSTtom)) NOT IN (
        SELECT rtrim(ltrim(Anv + '' + Startdate + '' + Slutdate + '' + Kstfrom + '' + KSTtom))
        FROM Agresso.Attestregler_history
        )

UNION ALL
```

and at the same time I want to update the Eskalera column in the `Agresso.Attestregler` with the new value from this:

```
convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,@antalkorningar,(convert(datetime,Startdate))),112)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in the current statement?

Thanx in advance,

Comment: You might want to use `OUTPUT` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx. It would require one or two extra steps, but it would be very simple

Comment: Use the formatting features please, to help us understand your question and improve your chance to get an answer. Also please read the [help] entry about [ask]

Comment: Since version 2008, you can do *upserts* using the `MERGE` statement. Alternatively, add an `OUTPUT` clause to your INSERT, as Sam proposed.

Comment: How does upserts work? Any link or example?

Comment: @iDevlop As far as I know, there is no way to update/insert on two different tables using `MERGE`, you need a target and a source table. But I don't have a lot of experience with `MERGE` and if there is a way, I would like to learn how

Comment: Google SQL UPSERT to get all the links and examples you could want.

Comment: @Sam cd: you're right, I did not read well enough to see that updates/inserts where required for 2 different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please test following script?
I simplified the fields of the tables, you need to modify below script
Please note that there is an [SQL OUTPUT clause with INSERT statement](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/insert-into-two-tables-using-t-sql-output-clause.aspx)
Some of the inserted data is stored in a temp table while Insert command is being executed.
So you insert data into two tables. Then I use the temp table data to update the original table for Eskalera

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
Id int,Eskalera datetime
)
insert Into Biztalk.Attestregler(Id,STATUS,Kstfrom,KSTtom)
    output inserted.Id, getdate() into #temp (Id, Eskalera)
SELECT Id, 'A', Kstfrom, KSTtom
FROM Agresso.Attestregler
WHERE Id not in (SELECT Id FROM Agresso.Attestregler_history)

update Biztalk.Attestregler
set
    Eskalera = t.Eskalera
from Biztalk.Attestregler a
inner join #temp t on a.Id = t.Id
```

Comment: It seems to work Eralper, but I'll test it in more detail tomorrow. -cheers